Python behave test is failing, but code working by itself
I have code about game "Towns", where you are naming a town and the next town should start from last char of last town.
By itself it seems to work, but an error occurs during testing.
def formatCityName( name_city):
    return name_city.strip().lower().capitalize()

class Town_Game:
    def startGame(self,name_city):
        self.cities = set()
        self.cache = set()
        char = None
        if not self.cities:
            self.cities = {formatCityName(x) for x in open("C:/Users/bodmi/PycharmProjects/test3/cities.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8").readlines() if x.strip()}

        try:
            lastChar = self.isCorrectTown(name_city, char)
            return str(lastChar)
        except Exception as e:
            return f"Error processing town: {str(e)}"

    def isCorrectTown(self, name_city, char):
        if (name_city in self.cities) and (name_city[0] == char or char is None) and not (name_city in self.cache):
            return name_city[-1]
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"{name_city} is not a valid city or has already been used.")

print(Town_Game.startGame(Town_Game,"London")) #outputs "n"

Feature:
Feature: I want to play a game Towns

    Scenario: When i saying town name
        Given Game starts
        When I saying new town "London"
        Then New town should be added to cache and next town should start from "n"

Test:
from behave import given, when, then
from town_game import Town_Game, formatCityName


@given('Game starts')
def step_given_calculator_running(context):
    context.game = Town_Game()


@when('I saying new town {name_city}')
def step_when_enter_expression(context, name_city):
    context.result = context.game.startGame(name_city)


@then('New town should be added to cache and next town should start from {expected_result}')
def step_then_verify_result(context, expected_result):
    assert context.result == expected_result, \
        f"Expected '{expected_result}', but got '{context.result}'"

When I run test, it says: Expected '"n"', but got 'Error processing town: "London" is not a valid city or has already been used.'
Why?

formatCityName does not need to be imported in the tests, it's not used there.

This is the problem:
@when('I saying new town {name_city}')
When I saying new town "London"

These two things don't exactly match.  The @when step definition does not have quotes, but you are using quotes when you call the step.
So your game code received "London" as the actual guess, including the quote marks.
I think you need to either adjust the step definition to include the quotes so they are not treated as part of the value, or adjust the step call to not include quotes.

That's worked, Thanks
